# Can I install windows 8.1 update 1 on a 30GB ssd

Tags: windows-8, ssd

I have a computer with an *empty* 30GB SSD, and no place for another drive. Can I place a usable Win 8.1 on this drive, or should I buy a bigger one?

I see in the comments that moving the `Users` folder is a bad idea. Can I fit everything I need into 30 GB?

Does Windows 10 take smaller place?

Comment: Update 1 is only 1GB.  You can manually download each required file to any drive you want, run each one, if you want to do that.  I would just use Windows Update since you don't know how to do it.  How you move the Users folder in Windows is a well document thing, which I don't support, because it seems everyone that does it comes to this website when it goes bad.  The Users directory was not designed to be moved.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/703409/install-windows-8-on-a-laptop-with-20gb-ssd/ (can't vote to close as duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the new WIMBoot feature, Windows doesn't requires a lot of space. This feature was added with the 8.1 Update to make sure Windows 8.1 also runs on Tablets with 16GB storage. So 30GB is enough to run it as WIMBoot.

Microsoft explained this here in detail:

[**Windows Image File Boot (WIMBoot) Overview**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn594399.aspx)
**[What is Windows Image Boot (WIMBoot)?](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2014/04/10/what-is-windows-image-boot-wimboot.aspx)**